# Error:The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i am trying to make working a simple example a form request but I am stuck below is my simple code

Here is the register.blade.php file:

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Form Example</title>
   </head>

   <body>
    <form action = "/user/register" method = "post">
        @csrf
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Name</td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Username</td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Password</td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan = "2" align = "center">
                  <input type = "submit" value = "Register" />
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

here is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function init($id)
    {
        echo "<br>Test Controller." . $id;
    }
    public function showProfile()
    {
        echo "<br>showProfile.";
    }
    public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
      //Retrieve the name input field
      $name = $request->input('name');
      echo 'Name: '.$name;
      echo '<br>';

      //Retrieve the username input field
      $username = $request->username;
      echo 'Username: '.$username;
      echo '<br>';

      //Retrieve the password input field
      $password = $request->password;
      echo 'Password: '.$password;
    }
}
```

here is the route files

```
Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('register');
});
Route::post('/user/register', [TestController::class, 'showProfile']);
```

the error that i code is this

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

what i miss?? i think the problem its too simple but i cant find it maybe the problem is that the register view file is a blade file and not a single php

Comment: What is the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @sta  GET|HEAD | user/register | generated::zxB9e4RtDOLdvCf3 | App\Http\Controllers\TestController@postRegister | web

Comment: Try with `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: its working now thnxxxxxx!!!

Comment: Cheers, have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php artisan route:clear
```

solve my problem thnx to @sta for this observation